# Can I use a Kobo Aura HD without internet?

Tags: windows-7

The website says it needs to be setup, which requires Internet, one way or another. I've been wondering, after I set it up, if I could just download books on my computer, transfer it onto the Kobo, and just read, without having WiFi on, Also, are there ads on the Kobo Aura HD?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Calibre can transfer books to many ereaders.

Comment: Many eReaders require initial setup to "register" the device. Though I can't address the Kobo Auara HD in particular, Nooks and Kindles will not work without registration, unless they are rooted.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik he said *after* he sets it up.  So it shouldnt matter.

Comment: Sorry I missed that... and as @Ketari states, Calibre is *superb*, not only for transferring and syncing libraries, but also for cataloging and translating between formats for different devices, e.g. MOBI, EPUB etc.